# meaning of the phrasal verb "put together" in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> People had to try for thousands of years before they knew how to put together days, weeks, months, and years.

This sentence is a passage from an article about "Inventing calendar". The phrasal verb I am so confused is "put together".
Does this sentence mean that "they try to create days by combining hours, weeks by combining days, months by combining weeks" or "they try to form a calendar by joining days, weeks, months, and year together"?

Answer (score 2):

**Put together** (phrasal verb)
according to the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/put-together) you can put together some parts of something to make a ready-to-use product 
*(e.g. assemble some parts of furniture to make a table **or** some different articles was assembled and collated in order to make one story)*

> has idiomatic meaning *(e.g. put yourself together)* - you can't assemble yourself, it means put together your thoughts
>
> also it has slightly different meaning as *(assembled, combined; (occasionally) makeshift, improvised)*

your sentence:

> People had to try for thousands of years before they knew how **to put together** days, weeks, months, and years
>
> **means to make the right** [**order**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/order) for days when the only one month should have 28 days and one time out of four years it turns 29 days month so-called 'leap-year'; Consequently, year becomes the entity that has some exact order for days it could be changed due to order